How to fix missing glyphs when using starship prompt in Hyper terminal
As a programmer, I like to use the terminal prompt plugin Starship which shows very useful information to me as a programmer when programming: exit code, runtime of previous command, versions of relevant runtimes, git branch checked out, etc.
After I installed the terminal prompt software Starship, my prompt shows empty rectangles rather than the special symbols I expect:
tldr on  mas-lucky via  v22.6.0 via  v3.12.5 took 2s
❯

How do I fix this? I'm using Vercel's Hyper terminal on macOS

You need to install a Nerd font, if not already present on the system, e.g. doing:
brew install font-fira-code-nerd-font

and add that font as the preferred font in the Hyper config file, commonly at ~/.hyper.js:
module.exports = {
    config: {
        ...
        // font family with optional fallbacks
        fontFamily: '"FiraCode Nerd Font", Menlo, "DejaVu Sans Mono", Consolas, "Lucida Console", monospace',
        ...

Make sure you edit the existing key fontFamily, not creating a duplicate key.
You need to wrap the font name in double quotes if it includes white space, as it does in the case of "FiraCode Nerd Font".
